# Android Studio emulator on amd with Windows 10 Home

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, amd-processor

Is it possible to run an android emulator with Android Studio if i have an AMD processor and windows 10 Home? When i try to install HAXM i got the error "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed." from what i understood HAXM is only available for intel processor or if you have Hyper-V, but Hyper-V is not available for Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Home Edition is not really a good dev environment. Upgrade to 10 Pro to use Hyper.-V Platform

Comment: don't edit the question, post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enabling Windows Hypervisor Platform in windows features worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After running the script from the link below, Hyper V has been installed successfully

But in order to start the Hyper V go to:

Start Menu –> Windows Administrative Tools –> Hyper-V.

https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/

Thank you all for your help.